# AG-Grid (React): Is there a way to get a quickFilterAggregateText of a node, before a quickfilter is applied?

Tags: ag-grid

I'm looking for a method to calculate the 'quickFilterAggregateText' without applying a quick filter to the grid. When I use 'resetQuickFilter', it leads to null values in 'quickFilterAggregateText' instead of recalculating them.

From what I gather, the quickFilterAggregateText seems to be a combination of all column values. Could there be a way to access the function responsible for this calculation?

Any insights or suggestions.